# How to determine node on TreeView on Mouse and Key event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView`. The user can navigate it with the mouse or keyboard. I have event handlers for both.
The mouse click event works well, but I have a problem in that the `KeyEventArg` has no knowledge of the nodes in the tree (as does `TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs`).
So how does the code know where the user is in the TreeView when using the up and down keys?

MyView.Designer.cs

```
this.trvApproval.NodeMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.trvApproval_NodeMouseClick);
this.trvApproval.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.trvApproval_KeyUp);
```

MyView.cs

```
private void trvApproval_NodeMouseClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    this.trvApproval.SelectedNode = eventArgs.Node;
}

private void trvApproval_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    // No knowledge of tree in KeyEventArgs
    if (eventArgs.KeyValue == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Down))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("trvApproval_KeyPress Down: " + eventArgs.KeyValue);
    }
    else if (eventArgs.KeyValue == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Up))
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("trvApproval_KeyPress Up: " + eventArgs.KeyValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to handle keyboard or mouse events, just handle [`AfterSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of `TreeView` control. The event will raise when you use mouse or keyboard to select nodes. `e.Node` is the node you are looking for:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    //e.Node is what you are looking for.
}
```

Comment: Oic .. how to add the event handler? `this.trvApproval.AfterSelect += ?`

Comment: Yes, it's like other event handlers. Or use the designer.

Comment: I'm asking what would complete the statement in my previous comment.

Comment: `this.trvApproval.AfterSelect + = treeView1_AfterSelect;`

Comment: You can use the designer. `AfterSelect` is the default event of `TreeView`, so if you double click on the control, then the designer will generate both the event handler method and assigns it to the control (generating some code in designer.cs). Also as another option, you can select the control in design surface and the in properties window, choose events toolbar button and from the list of events, just double click on `AfterSelect` or choose an existing handler from list.